# Search AngularJS resource using query string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following resource set up in my AngularJS app:

```
var phonecatServices = angular.module('phonecatServices', ['ngResource']);

phonecatServices.factory('Phone', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('phones/:phoneId.json', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{phoneId:'phones'}, isArray:true}
    });
  }]);
```

And by default they are listed like so via the controller:

```
var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Phone',
  function($scope, Phone) {
    $scope.phones = Phone.query();
    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
  }]);
```

As you can see I already have a filter but I want a query string based search so that I can use the History to get back to the results after choosing a record, etc.

*First question I have here, is that this list actually uses phones.json for the data but I don't specify this anywhere in the code... so how does this work? Presume some magic is happening but I can't see it.*

So back to the initial question, I have built the following search controller:

```
phonecatControllers.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'Phone',
    function ($scope, $http, $location, Phone) {
        $scope.keywords = $location.search()['q'];
        // The function that will be executed on button click (ng-click="search()")
        $scope.search = function() {    
            $location.path('phones').search('q', $scope.keywords);

            $scope.phones= Phone.query($scope.keywords);

        }
    }]);
```

So it should use the query string to find the results. But how do I do this? It seems very transparent how the data is pulled from the JSON file. The method should also list data if the query string is there on page load... so perhaps this should be combined into one controller for both the list and search?

The code above doesn't filter the JSON data when I do a search... so the query string isn't being used... but I presume it's because I don't understand how the app knows to look in the 'phones.json' file?

---

The HTML for the filtering and search:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Filter:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input ng-model="$parent.query">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Sort by:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select ng-model="$parent.orderProp">
            <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
            <option value="age">Newest</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <form class="form-search" ng-submit="search()">
        <label>Search:</label>
        <input type="text" name="q" ng-model="keywords" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Keywords...">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="search()">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The HTML for the list:

```
<ul class="phones">
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp"
    class="thumbnail phone-listing">
        <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}" class="thumb"><img ng-src="{{phone.imageUrl}}"></a>
        <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}">{{phone.name}}</a>
        <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Answering you side question: in the resource config, `params` are interpolated into the URL. Your URL is `'phones/:phoneId.json'`. The `:` denotes that `phoneId` is a variable part which should be replaced by a value. Your `params` object contains a `phoneId` key, so Angular uses its value to replace `:phoneId`. The URL ends up being `'phones/phones.json'`. No magic here. :)

Comment: Ah, you mean this bit: `params:{phoneId:'phones'}`. Thanks that clears that bit up. Any ideas for searching the list? Thanks.

Comment: About the main question: I'm a bit confused. Are you expecting the `$resource` service to perform a search inside the content of the file? Because it cannot do that. `$resource` makes request to your server but does not perform any transformation on the data returned. You can do a search client-side though. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, basically I can filter the data already via a filter input on the repeater (it happens in real-time as you type), e.g. `<li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">` but I'm wanting to add a full form that uses a query string and then filters the data that way instead if that makes sense? It should return objects in the JSON file that match the query.

Comment: OK so after re-reading the question, I've come to understand that you already have a working as-you-type search, but you want the terms the user entered and the results to remain when you go to another page and come back. Is that it?

Comment: Yes that's correct! The query string part is already working fine and works great, I just need to use it to filter the data...

Comment: Can you provide the code of the view (the HTML)?

Comment: Added the HTML for the search form and the list.

Comment: `filter:query` -> where is `query` defined?

Comment: The input field has its model set to query: `ng-model="$parent.query"`. But that bit all works fine!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59525/discussion-between-hugo-wood-and-cameron).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so to ensure that I understand correctly:

- you already have a as-you-type search using [Angular's filter filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)
- this search is implemented using an input bound to a variable named `query`
- you are trying to persist the search terms when changing view and coming back
- you want to persist it in the URL

You don't need the new controller or the new input. In the `PhoneListCtrl` controller, add `$scope.query = $location.search().q`. This will read the `q` parameter from the URL and write the value in `query`, which will automatically fill the input and filter your results.

To do the reverse (ie writing the value of `query` to the URL), add a `ng-change` attribute to your input (`<input ng-model="query" ng-change="queryChanged()"/>)`, and add the corresponding function to your controller:

```
$scope.queryChanged = function () {
    $location.search('q', $scope.query)
}
```

This function will be executed every time the `query` changes and it will update the URL accordingly. Everything should work out now. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qwd0zg9/1/).

As a side note, persisting the query in the URL might not be the best idea, as it will remain visible is the user's browser after they have left the search view. You could use [session storage](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/web-storage/Storage/sessionStorage), for example.

Comment: What if I wanted to filter on a particular thing? E.g. just the phone name? As the Angular filter filter (as you put it) searches on everything... Any examples of more tailored control?

Comment: Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). `| filter:{name: query}` to look only in the name. If that's not enough, you can either pass a predicate function to filter or create your own filter. It's all documented.

Comment: Okay, so would there ever be a time when you'd search for something in Angular and NOT use the filter? Or is that the correct way to search in an Angular app?

Comment: Ah okay, I'll have a play with it tomorrow. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: It is the correct way to search. If you need to search using JavaScript (rather than in the view), it is possible to inject the filter filter (or any other filter for that matter) in a controller or service: `.controller(function ($scope, filterFilter) { filterFilter(listOfStuffToSearchIn, thingToSearchFor)}`.

Comment: To avoid confusion around the word 'filter'. Filters are a type of component in Angular that support the `| nameOfTheFilter:param1:param2` syntax in the view. Angular provide several filters out of the box: `orderBy`, `number`, `uppercase`...It just happens that one of those filters is named filter. That's why I say 'the filter filter' to talk about that one specifically. The filter filter is the one usually used to search in lists.

Comment: What if I wanted to stop the instant search? So the filter ONLY happens when the user submits the form? I've got it to filter on type and also do the query on submit (instead of as you type). But I'd like to stop the instant search... This is the code I have: http://pastebin.com/7zfpaF17

Comment: This is another question entirely. Post it as a separate question and come back here with the link. :)

Comment: Haha is it more complicated than a simple switch off then?

Comment: It's not a question of simple or complicated, it a question of using StackOverflow the way it is meant to be used.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381559/stop-angularjs-instant-search Asked here.