# Stop AngularJS Instant Search

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have built a simple search form in my AngularJS app, that as you type uses the built in filter magic of angular to filter a list of phones. I've wrapped mine in a form as when the user submits the form it ALSO does the filter, but creates a query string so you can navigate away from the list and return etc.

HTML:

```
<form class="form-search" ng-submit="$parent.queryChanged()">
        <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="filter">Filter:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                        <input name="q" ng-model="$parent.query" id="filter" type="text">
                </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Phone', '$location',
        function($scope, Phone, $location) {
                $scope.query = $location.search()['q'];
                $scope.queryChanged = function () {
                        $location.search('q', $scope.query)
                }
                $scope.phones = Phone.query();
                $scope.orderProp = 'age';
        }]);
```

What I want to do is disable the instant search, so the user ONLY submits the form and never gets the results on keyup alone. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 different variables for the ng-model of the input (`ng-model="$parent.query"`) and the parameter of the filter (`| filter:filterQuery`). This will make the input and the filter unrelated to each other. Then when the form is submitted (in `queryChanged`), update the filter parameter with the value of the ng-model (`$scope.filterQuery = $scope.query`).

Comment: Tried that, but after submitting the form (query string now added or updated) the results are not filtered unless I hit submit a second time. **Presume because I have updated the filterQuery, but the list has already been rendered?**

Comment: Updating filterQuery should trigger a new render. Could you make a fiddle that reproduces the behavior you're witnessing?

Comment: Ah it was because I didn't use the query outside of the queryChanged. Thanks.