# Access unique JSON record via http.get in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ngmodel, angular-http

Rather than gathering my order data from one JSON file I know need to access individual records displayed in JSON. Is it possible to adapt the http.get request so it has a variable option(for the order number) and change the ng-repeat to display individual records.

So on list.html, if I search for order ref 12145 it will pull the data from http://example.com/api/booking/get/guest/12145 and the ng-repeat output in list.html and detail.html will display that exact order.

I assume the ng-model search query will need to be appended onto the http.get url?

Here is the code in a Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/eS28uBh2y1tmbAP597zM?p=catalogue

and a gif showing what I am trying to do (search order ref, append to url, fetch data)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJzTZ.gif

```
  // Ionic Starter App

  // angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
  // 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
  // the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
  angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {



      if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

        // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
        // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
        // a much nicer keyboard experience.
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
      }
      if(window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      }
    });
  })

  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('tabs', {
        url: '/tab',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
      })
      .state('tabs.home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
          'home-tab' : {
           templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tabs.list', {
        url: '/list',
        views: {
          'list-tab' : {
           templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
           controller: 'ListController'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tabs.detail', {
        url: '/list/:aId',
        views: {
          'list-tab' : {
           templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html',
           controller: 'ListController'
          }
        }
      })

        // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/home');

  })

  .controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state','$cordovaBluetoothSerial', '$window', '$location', function($scope, $http, $state, $cordovaBluetoothSerial, $window, $location) {
          $http.get('http://example.com/api/booking/get/guest/{{ query }}').success(function(data) {
            $scope.orders = data;
            $scope.whichorder = $state.params.aId;

          })

          $scope.orders = [];

           function onPay(order) {
           var itemsArr = [];
           var invoice = {};
           var myItems = {};
           var myItem = {};
           //var order = $scope.orders[];

           myItem['name'] = "Sphero";
           myItem['description'] = "A robotic ball that can be controlled via apps";
           myItem['quantity'] = "1.0";
           myItem['unitPrice'] = order.bkor_subtotal;
           myItem['taxRate'] = '0.0';
           myItem['taxName'] = 'Tax';
           itemsArr.push(myItem);
           myItems['item'] = itemsArr;

           invoice['itemList'] = myItems;
           invoice['paymentTerms'] = 'DueOnReceipt';
           invoice['currencyCode'] = 'GBP';
           invoice['discountPercent'] = '0';
           invoice['merchantEmail'] ="email@email.com";
           invoice['payerEmail'] = 'foo@bar.com';

           var returnUrl = order.bkor_seatcount;
           var retUrl = encodeURIComponent(returnUrl + "?{result}?Type={Type}&InvoiceId={InvoiceId}&Tip={Tip}&Email={Email}&TxId={TxId}");
           //var pphereUrl = "paypalhere://takePayment/?returnUrl={{returnUrl}}&invoice=%7B%22merchantEmail%22%3A%22{{merchantEmails}}%22,%22payerEmail%22%3A%22{{payerEmails}}%22,%22itemList%22%3A%7B%22item%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22{{name}}%22,%22description%22%3A%22{{description}}%22,%22quantity%22%3A%221.0%22,%22unitPrice%22%3A%22{{price}}%22,%22taxName%22%3A%22Tax%22,%22taxRate%22%3A%220.0%22%7D%5D%7D,%22currencyCode%22%3A%22{{currency}}%22,%22paymentTerms%22%3A%22DueOnReceipt%22,%22discountPercent%22%3A%220.0%22%7D";
           var pphereUrl = "paypalhere://takePayment/v2?returnUrl=" + retUrl;
           pphereUrl = pphereUrl + "&accepted=cash,card,paypal";
           pphereUrl = pphereUrl + "&step=choosePayment";
           pphereUrl = pphereUrl + '&invoice=' + escape(JSON.stringify(invoice));
           console.log(pphereUrl);

           return pphereUrl;

           }

          $scope.pay = function (order) {
          var url = onPay(order);
          window.open(url, "_system");
          }
  }]);
```

Comment: Is there any way you could get some server side code like PHP or Node.JS running to parse the JSON faster than client side? It would be ideal to store in a database. If you must use a static JSON file, could you make each index be equivalent to the id? so for id=12145, the item is the 12146th item in the list (starting from zero). So, then you can get all the guests and just do a `guests[guestID]` to get the correct guest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search AngularJS resource using query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366913/search-angularjs-resource-using-query-string)